# 14.04 installation failing due to grub2, internet issues

Tags: boot, networking, grub2, uefi

**TL;DR:** just put together a computer (no other OS) and am installing Ubuntu 14.04. Doesn't connect to internet and I get a grub error when I go through the installation steps.

I just put together my first computer with the following parts:

- Asus Z270-AR
- Intel i5-7600K
- 8GB Corsaire RAM
- PNY 240GB SSD

The system boots up and all the lights and fans (to my knowledge) are working well. I've created a 14.04 USB stick, but when I start the install steps, I notice that my internet connections (WiFi and ethernet) are not detected -- nothing shows up in the connections dropdown menu. Given that, I opt to not install the extra packages and move on. I go through the normal steps and begin installation. This always fails at the same spot:

> "Installing the 'grub2' package...

The following pop-up appears.

> The 'grub-efi-amd64-signed' package filed to install into /target/. Without the GRUB boot loader, the installed system will not boot.

I've read on other posts that I should ensure my computer is connected to the internet, but most internet debug posts I've read require me to have another OS installed.

What steps can I take to move forward?

Comment: **UPDATE** To get the ethernet up, I went into the Asus BIOS and enabled the LAN settings on the On-Board Devices page.

Comment: Try with Ubuntu 16.04.1 (or better, 16.04.2, which is due out any day now), or with 16.10. A 14.04 installation, especially if it's with the original 14.04 and not with the newer 14.04.5, uses an older kernel that may be lacking important drivers; and it's likely to have other EFI-related bugs. If that fails, try booting with my [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) on a USB flash drive. You can then try installing `grub-efi` or rEFInd, and with any luck get better error messages with clues about the cause of the failure.

Answer (score 0):

You probably didn't make good bootablе USB. Retry with [UNetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/) .  Or connect to internet and let them fix. :D

Comment: Hmm, I did use UNetbootin to make the USB! As for the internet... yeah I'm not sure how I should approach fixing it. The ethernet is plugged in and blinking, so I'd expect it to work, but that's unfortunately not the case.